# Spring MVC The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

I have a war project with a single controller class (MainController.class) with a public function index() that returns a string that was the last time I checked the name of the view you were forwarding onto - and a single jsp named "index.jsp".  The views are in /main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/jsp/.  MainController.java:

```
@Controller
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContextProvider mObjApplicationContextProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ScheduleService mObjScheduleService;

    protected ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return(getApplicationContextProvider().getApplicationContext());
    }

    protected ApplicationContextProvider getApplicationContextProvider()
    {
        return(mObjApplicationContextProvider);
    }

    protected Object getBean(final Class<?> clsBean)
    {
        return(getApplicationContext().getBean(clsBean));
    }

    protected Object getBean(final String sBeanName)
    {
        return(getApplicationContext().getBean(sBeanName));
    }

    protected ScheduleService getScheduleService()
    {
        return(mObjScheduleService);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index()
    {
        return("index");
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```

My configuration xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.draconia.church" />

    <bean class="net.draconia.ApplicationContextProvider" />

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:sql9.freemysqlhosting.net/sql9158326" />
        <property name="username" value="sql9158326" />
        <property name="password" value="MqX7sbacgB" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

For some reason I get the error in my browser when I go to "http://localhost:8080/Ushering/": 404 - "The requested resource is not available."

I can't find anything in the logs (but can post if necessary) to tell me WHAT file or resource is unable to be available.  It seems to be able to find the controller because in the one log file it mentions the Request Mapping for the controller.  What could it be?

Edit: The WAR file is Ushering as is defined in the pom file and also in the web.xml as the name of the project so I would think the context would be Ushering as well and anything in the Spring application side of things would be after /Ushering so if I set the requestmapping to /Hello then the URL should be localhost:8080/Ushering/Hello.

Edit: My Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ushering</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/Ushering-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ushering</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/s</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file?

Comment: Added it as an edit

Comment: I got it!  There was a typo I noticed when I posted the web.xml - /s in the url-pattern near the bottom.  It should be / and only /.  I removed the 's', clean compile war:war-ed it and it came up as I'm expecting :-D Thanks for poking me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your MainController class there is only one request handling method which returns "index". It is mapped to "/" meaning that when you type **localhost:8080** it gives you index file in return. Therefore instead of typing **localhost:8080/Ushering** enter **localhost:8080**. It would work. But if you want to enter **localhost:8080/Ushering** then change the request mapping in controller file to following.

@RequestMapping(value="/Ushering")

```
public String index()
{
    return("index");
}
```

It would return you the index file.

Comment: I don't see how that could be - The war is Ushering.war and it creates a context Ushering folder under the WebApps folder in Tomcat when I copy the war file over to webapps.  If I type http://localhost:8080 I get the "If you're seeing this you've officially installed Tomcat!  Congratulations!" page.